# Reuse SSD storage for another laptop, need other configuration besides formatting?

Tags: 20.04, ssd

I have a doubt regarding the computer's SSD storage, in my notebook 1 I use an SSD where everything is installed with ubuntu, I have another SSD in another notebook 2 that also has a version of ubuntu installed. I wanted to transfer one of the storages I have in laptop 2 to my laptop 1. I wanted to know, in addition to formatting the storage, I would have to do another configuration to insert it in laptop 1, to be able to have both storages at the same time.

Comment: It looks like you are confusing the term memory with hard disk. An SSD is a hard disk. Memory are chips on the mother board. You question needs to be clear. You do not and can not format memory. Please edit the question and clarify what it is you are trying to do. Do not answer in comments edit the question.

Comment: "Memory" means RAM.  "Storage" means HDD or SSD.  Which are you referring to?>

Comment: I apologize for the error. Over here everything is the same. @Thomas Ward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By memory, do you mean RAM? You don't need to format anything. Turn off both laptops, swap the RAM, and you are done.

Similarly, for SSD, you don't need to format unless you want to remove the existing data/operating system in it.

Comment: I appreciate help. I managed to solve. @Archisman Panigrahi